# Spark Structured Streaming - Applying a data transformation to each row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming and would like to add a column that contains a unique timestamp for each row.  For example, here are the contents of an input test file:

| id | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | William | Smith |
| 101 | Oliver | Davis |
| 102 | James | Wilson |

I would like the output to be something like this (notice the unique timestamp for each row):

| id | fname | lname | epoch_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | William | Smith | 1686854220 |
| 101 | Oliver | Davis | 1686854221 |
| 102 | James | Wilson | 1686854222 |

However, my actual result looks like this:

| id | fname | lname | epoch_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | William | Smith | 1686854220 |
| 101 | Oliver | Davis | 1686854220 |
| 102 | James | Wilson | 1686854220 |

Here is some code that can be used to reproduce my actual result using the input test file shown above:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("add_timestamp_to_row")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("id", LongType)
      .add("fname", StringType)
      .add("lname", StringType)

    val df_from_file = spark.readStream
      .format("csv")
      .option("path","/tmp/test/*.csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("header", "True")
      .load()

    df_from_file.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")

    val df_from_sql = spark.sql(
    """ select
        id,
        fname,
        lname,
        unix_timestamp() as epoch_timestamp
        from temp_view
    """)

    val out_to_console = df_from_sql.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I have tried a variety of approaches, but so far have been not succeeded due to the use of Structured Streaming. For instance, I have tried to use monotonically_increasing_id and adding it to the base epoch time, however monotonically_increasing_id is not supported for Structured Streaming. I also tried using zipWithIndex, but could not get it to work with Structured Streaming. Another attempt involved using ROW_NUMBER in SQL, but no luck there either.

The research I have done leads me to believe that I should use Foreach (or possibly ForeachBatch), as discussed at: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach

The problem I am running into with using Foreach is that the documentation is limited and I cannot find an instance showing how someone actually implemented such a solution. Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use UDF to get what you want. I am assuming timestamp value  depends on some existing column hence if condition inside udf code. you can change this code to add any other condition or logic to return timestamp too.
In below code i have added addTimestamp UDF and used it after reading data from file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


object test {



val addTimestamp = udf((*required col to decide timestamp*) => if(yourcondition for each row/col) return timestamp




  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("add_timestamp_to_row")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("id", LongType)
      .add("fname", StringType)
      .add("lname", StringType)

    val df_from_file = spark.readStream
      .format("csv")
      .option("path","/tmp/test/*.csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("header", "True")
      .load()

   df_with_time =  df_from_files.withColumn("timestamp",addTimestamp(*required col for deciding timestamp*))

    val out_to_console = df_from_sql.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

PS :https://medium.com/@achilleus/spark-udfs-we-can-use-them-but-should-we-use-them-2c5a561fde6d . Just FYI on UDFs